# graphics issue-- wrapfig and floatflt packages

Tags: graphics, wrapfigure

I can't seem to get a graphic included without including the path.  Can somebody help me with this?

```
\begin{figure}[h]
    \includegraphics[width=0.35\textwidth]{C:/Users/zach/Documents/My Dropbox/AMATH 383/fig1.pdf}
    \label{fig:fig1}
\end{figure}

\usepackage{wrapfig}
I've also tried:
\begin{wrapfig}[t]{0.5\textwidth}
 \begin{center}
    \includegraphics[width=0.35\textwidth]{fig1.pdf}
    \label{fig:fig1}
 \end{center}
\end{wrapfig}
```

Comment: If you get an error message, you could edit your question and add it.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use spaces in file names or paths. If you really need spaces there, load the [`grffile`](http://ctan.org/pkg/grffile) package:

```
\usepackage{grffile}
```

Usually it's good to use relative paths instead of absolute. This makes moving or copying your project easier, to another path, disk or computer: you don't need to change all paths.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of including the fully expanded path of the image, you could use the relative path to your main document. For example, if your main `.tex` document is in the folder `<root>`, and your image `fig1.pdf` is in the folder `<root>/image`, then you can include the image with

```
\includegraphics[...]{image/fig1.pdf}% include <root>/image/fig1.pdf
```

Alternatively, you could specify a folder where LaTeX should search for images (graphics in general) by using

```
\graphicspath{{image/}}% Graphics are in folder '<root>\image'
\includegraphics[...]{fig1.pdf}% include <root>/fig1.pdf or <root>/image/fig1.pdf
```

Note the trailing `/` in the `\graphicspath` command, as well as the double nested braces `{{}}`. Also, since `\` has a different meaning in LaTeX, folders can be specified using `/`, even on Windows; there is not alternative for this when using `\graphicspath`.

More on the latter use of graphics inclusion via path specification can be found on the [TeX FAQ](https://texfaq.org/FAQ-graphicspath).

Answer (score 0):

There is a solution alternative to both of the above solutions. I've put the images and the .tex file in the same directory. Then it doesn't need any path, nor absolute path, neither relative path. Is there any drawback on that?

Comment: No technical drawback, but if your project becomes big, it’s annoying when the folder becomes crowded.

Comment: I agree with you. You're right.